# javascript getelementbyid is null

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is a strange one Ive been banging my head against a wall for the past 2 days. Have done something similar before so not sure what the issue is.

You can see working page here: http://psssoftware.net/forms.html

I am trying to hide the "testbox" on the right but when I try to get it by id there is nothing there. There are no other elements with the same tag name, the id is correct. There has to be something I am missing hopefully another pair of eyes will see.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">


var x = document.getElementById('col-ab-affUSLF');
var y = document.getElementById('col-c-affUSLF');
x.style.width = 'auto !important';
y.style.display = 'none !important';


</script>
```

Thanks,
Blake

Comment: Could you please post your relevant JavaScript? If you really typed it lowercase (`getelementbyid`) then it won't work, because it's supposed to be camel-cased: `getElementById('idName')`

Answer (score 4):

**The element with the given ID does not exist *at the time getElementById was called***. There is a reason why [a number of] frameworks "wait for DOM ready" (e.g. onload) before doing DOM manipulation (including trying to get an element with a given ID).

Happy coding.

Comment: I think you are exactly right. I am blind. Ill will confirm once i get home. Thankyou

Comment: Frameworks don't wait for anything, using a DOMready function is up to the programmer.

Comment: Wrapped it in a function called it in the onload event worked exactly as expected. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unneeded double quote in this line:

```
y.style.display = 'none !important"';
```

It looks like it's throwing off your script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the source, this is your js:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 


    var x = document.getElementById('col-ab-affUSLF');
    var y = document.getElementById('col-c-affUSLF');
    x.style.width = 'auto !important';
    y.style.display = 'none !important"';


</script>
```

It looks like you have a extra **double quote "** in your `y.style.display = 'none !important"';`